# How to use SQL query to put 2 attributes from 2 tables into 1 table with 2 attribute

Tags: sql

Attribute 1 FROM the first table:

```
SELECT PUBLISHERFULLNAME 
FROM publisher 
WHERE publisher.PUBLISHERID IN (SELECT PUBLISHERID 
                                FROM published_by
                                WHERE published_by.BOOKDESCID IN (SELECT BOOKDESCID 
                                                                  FROM book
                                                                  WHERE book.SUBJECTID IN (SELECT SUBJECTID FROM subject
                                                                                           WHERE SUBJECTTYPE = 'DataBases'))
                                                                                             AND published_by.ROLE = 'Publisher')
```

The output of this first query:

[image]

Attribute 2 FROM the second table:

```
SELECT TITLE 
FROM book
WHERE book.SUBJECTID IN (SELECT SUBJECTID 
                         FROM subject
                         WHERE SUBJECTTYPE = 'DataBases')
```

The output from the second query:

[image]

I want to put this two into one table with 2 attributes, which is means display the publishers and title of the book at the same time. Can someone give me a hand.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Those 4 nested subqueries make me sad.

Comment: Hint:  Use `JOIN`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still in year 1 in the university,  still learning how to write a good query

Comment: Then go to office hours and ask your prof for help.

Comment: Hi, Gordon, I did try the INNER JOIN but when I run the query shows error, Could you teach me how I can put use the JOIN to combine this two query? Many thanks